# How to use FTP using Progress 4GL?

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

*Is there any way to send files from a local folder to an FTP folder using Progress?*

Comment: You need to post what you've already tried.

Comment: i`ve found an exemple on internet using the wininet.dll to connect , but i dont know if its right.
[link](http://www.oehive.org/node/456)

Comment: I'd like to know if there's a simple way in progress to connect to a ftp server.

Comment: Have you tried either of the examples that you have found?  They should both work.  If you have tried them and run into problems then you should show your code along with the resulting errors in your question.

Comment: Yeah , Actually it worked fine. But now the people who ask me to do that by using Ftp functions wants to change for webservice. But those examples they are working fine. The problem was in the ftp server, some settings wasn't right. Really appreciate all help!

Answer (score 1):

If you're running windows, then WinSCP is a good solution:
http://winscp.net/eng/index.php

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 
in my case I need send files from the FTP , using a progress function .
i need to call a function wich search files in a directory and send to the ftp

Comment: I've found this one 

http://www.peg.com/forums/peg/200311/msg00655.html

but i dont know how make it work

Comment: WinSCP can be used via the .NET interface, so it'll do what you need

Answer (score 0):

The "classic" way to do this is to send the commands that you would use if you were doing this manually to the built-in FTP command.

If you know that you want to send a file called "myfile.txt" to the server at 192.168.0.1 you might code:

```
define variable IPAddr   as character no-undo.
define variable fileName as character no-undo.

IPAddr = "192.168.0.1".
fileName = "myfile.txt".

output through value( "ftp -v -i -A" + IPAddr ).

put unformatted "put " + fileName skip.
put unformatted "bye " skip.
output close.
```

Obviously you can wrap that into a function and expand it to do more than a simple FTP PUT command (you might need to login...)

FTP is an insecure protocol and a PITA to work with.  If you have any influence over such things you really ought to try to use a better protocol.  SCP is *much* easier to use and has much better security.

Comment: Is it possible to save the "session" inside class? Meaning if we make a class wrapper for this. For example "connect()" method starts the ftp (the `output through value` statement, and we have 'put()' method which runs `put unformatted "bye " skip`? And on `disconnect()` we run `output close`?

Comment: Using FTP in 2015, when this question was first asked, was already a really, really bad idea. It has not become a better idea since then. Sure, you could wrap the code into a class and make it more modern but it is still a grossly insecure protocol that you need to move away from ASAP.

Comment: Thats a good point. I was thinking if this idea could be updated to use `openSSH` `sftp`, where each instance would represent a single `sftp` connection. Do you know if this `OUTPUT THROUGH` works with it?

Comment: I have not tried it but it seems like it should.

Answer (score -1):

```
DEFINE VARIABLE cFtpCommand AS CHARACTER   NO-UNDO.

cFtpCommand = "your FTP COMMAND".

OS-COMMAND SILENT NO-CONSOLE VALUE(cFtpCommand).
```