# What is the simplest way to ftp files using Progress 4gl code?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

This is on linux.   No windows code please.
Progress chui (11.6).

I have a process which creates csv files on linux.

A separate process (Program) will pick up these CSV files and ftp them to a given site.

What is the ftp command in Progress 4GL (Openedge)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use FTP using Progress 4GL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29707412/how-to-use-ftp-using-progress-4gl)

Comment: I don't know what doesn't "work" in the other FTP post, that sort of code has worked for me often enough, but the person who posted the question didn't provide any useful feedback or follow up so we'll probably never know.  Also -- it is not simple to test FTP these days.  Most firewalls that I work with block it because it is so insecure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to use os-command and curl.

Something similar to:

```
os-command value( substitute( 'curl -p --insecure  "ftp://&3:&1" --user "&4:&5" -T "&2" --ftp-create-dirs', localName, remoteName, serverName, usrName, usrPass ))).
```

FWIW you (or the party you are sending the file to) really shouldn't still be using FTP.  It is horribly insecure.  SCP/SFTP would be a much, much better choice.

Comment: thank you so much, I will try this.  i'm not sure what curl is.

Comment: Hi TOM, The substitute starement shows &1 to &6, however, only 5 are listed.  what is the sixth?   see:     , localName, remoteName, serverName, usrName, usrPass

Comment: "man curl", you will be amazed.  Curl is pretty much always installed on Linux.  It is available for every other platform (including Windows) but on AIX/Solaris/HPUX it might be a PITA to get your sysadmin to add it if you have to deal with that sort of thing.  It makes your life a whole lot easier when dealing with these things.

Comment: Also, the original -o should be -T

Comment: You might need to look into flags (like --insecure) and protocol (possibly ftps) as well as certificates for secure transfer depending on your specific environment but regardless of that: curl is a grea idea!

Comment: Hi Tom,   I tried the above ftp command , however, it wouldn't work but with bit of debugging, it turned out that there was an extra 'hyphen' in command.  I also did some research and found SFTP>

Comment: I removed the stray "-".  I don't have any actual FTP servers to test with so the specific options are a bit "hypothetical" (that's the "something similar to" aspect of my answer).  As I mentioned FTP is horribly insecure and you should use sftp or scp instead if you have any control over the other end of the transfer.

Answer (score -1):

I managed to work out code for sftp. I also tried code ftp which Tom provided.

Here's the code if anyone is interested (substitute info for serverName, remoteFile, usrName, usrPass)

```
/******************/
/* Ftpbob         */
/* ftp command    */
/* Author: 4gl    */
/******************/
/* upload using sftp (1)
curl  -k "sftp://83.46.38.23:22/CurlPutTest/" --user "testuser:testpassword" -T "C:\test\testfile.xml" --ftp-create-dirs
*/
/* upload using ftp (2)
os-command value(substitute('curl -p --insecure  "ftp://&1:&2" --user "&3:&4" -T "&5" --ftp-create-dirs', serverName, remoteFile, usrName, usrPass, localFile )).
*/

        Def var lvCommand  as char no-undo.
        Def var serverName as char no-undo initial "serv1". /* 92.25.04.69 */
        Def var usrName    as char no-undo initial "bob".
        Def var usrPass    as char no-undo initial "sumpass1".
        Def var remoteFile as char no-undo initial "/remoteDir/abc.csv".
        Def var localFile  as char no-undo initial "/localDir/123.csv".

        update
          serverName format "x(25)"
          usrName    format "x(25)"
          usrPass    format "x(25)"
          remoteFile format "x(25)"
          localFile  format "x(25)"
        with 1 col side-labels.

        /************************* FTP ***********************
        lvCommand = substitute
        ('curl -p --insecure "ftp://&1:&2" --user "&3:&4" -T "&5" --ftp-create-dirs',
              trim(serverName), 
              trim(remoteFile), 
              trim(usrName), 
              trim(usrPass),
              trim(localFile)
            ). 
        ******************************************************/

        /*** SFTP ***/
        lvCommand = substitute
        ('curl -k "sftp://&1:&2" --user "&3:&4" -T "&5" --ftp-create-dirs',
              trim(serverName), 
              trim(remoteFile), 
              trim(usrName), 
              trim(usrPass),
              trim(localFile)
            ). 

        message lvCommand
        view-as alert-box.

        os-command value(lvCommand).
```